# Unable to See Logs while running Unity Application on Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am new to Unity.
When I run the application on Windows I can see the logs in Console but when I run the same code on Android Device I am unable to see any logs.

Here is the code I am using for Logging.

```
Debug.Log("Here is the log");
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot see any logs in Unity Console windows if you are running your application on devices, you need to use android sdk tools to check the log on android device, unity logs will appear with a tag named 'Unity', hope this helps.